# MyEclipse React New Project Giving Error "Node 14+ version is required" with v18.16.0 Installed on Mac

Tags: node.js, reactjs, myeclipse

I just installed the Free trial version of MyEclipse by Genuitec.  I'm trying to create a new React project using the tool.  The app won't let me create a project as it cannot find v14+ of node

[!MyEclipse React Project Creation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26mgk.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26mgk.png)

When I check to see that node is installed and that node exists in my $PATH from the terminal, I can see `node`.

[image: Terminal Output]

I was expecting to be able to create the project based on this detail.  I'm to sure what to do next.  I appreciate your help.